Merge 1 column against the range of 2 columns in another pandas dataframe
I have the scenario where I need to merge the distance in 1 dataframe against the range (upper, lower) in another.
Note, I will need to merge along with other columns also.
Complete merge (courseId , obstacleType, raceDistance, fenceLabel, circuitNumber )
DF 1
| fallerId | courseId | obstacleType | raceDistance | fenceLabel | circuitNumber |
|----------|----------|--------------|--------------|------------|---------------|
| 1        | 1        | steeple      | 2500         | A          | 1             |
| 2        | 1        | steeple      | 3500         | F          | 1             |
| 3        | 1        | water        | 3500         | A          | 2             |
| 4        | 2        | steeple      | 3000         | B          | 1             |
| 5        | 2        | steeple      | 3000         | B          | 2             |

DF 2 Complete merge (courseId , obstacleType, [lowerRaceDistance, upperRaceDistance], fenceLabel, circuitNumber )
| courseId | obstacleType | lowerRaceDistance | upperRaceDistance | startingfenceLabel | fenceLabel | circuitNumber | sequence |
|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------------|------------|---------------|----------|
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | C          | 1             | 1        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | D          | 1             | 2        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | E          | 1             | 3        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | A          | 1             | 4        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | B          | 1             | 5        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | C          | 2             | 6        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | D          | 2             | 7        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | E          | 2             | 8        |

Desired DF
| fallerId | courseId | obstacleType | lowerRaceDistance | upperRaceDistance | startingfenceLabel | fenceLabel | circuitNumber | sequence |
|----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------------|------------|---------------|----------|
| 1        | 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | C          | 1             | 1        |
| 1        | 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | D          | 1             | 2        |
| 1        | 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | E          | 1             | 3        |
| 1        | 1        | steeple      | 2250              | 2750              | C                  | A          | 1             | 4        |

I need to keep rows leading up to the match in DF2 also, which makes this ask even trickier to apply a solution.
